# Query on point system of Express entry Canada

Tags: canada, resident-permit, ielts, language-test

I got an IELTS score being Non-English as primary language:

```
 Listening-6.5 Reading-6.0 Writing-6.0 Speaking-6.0
```

My wife has an IELTS score:

```
 Listening-7.0 Reading-5.5 Writing-6.0 Speaking-6.0
```

How many points do i score for language ability being primary applicant as per Express Entry System for Canada?

Comment: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp

Comment: @mkennedy Oh, so that mean, i got 4 points? whose points are equivalent to person who is 9 pointer in all bands? does not make sense to me

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have 16 points (4 per ability) and your wife has 12 (the 5.5 score doesn't give any points).

Comment: @mkennedy Do you mean, if i had scored 9.0 per ability, would i get same 4 points?

Comment: @mkennedy the 5.5 score doesn't give any points? But reading ability range is 4.0 – 9.0.

Comment: I have to ask--have you looked at the table in the link? To score points in the language ability section using IELTS, you have to get at least 6.0. Depending on the ability (reading, writing, etc.), the points vary based on your score. If you had 7.0 (except for reading, need 8.0), you'd score 6 points per ability. The max is 24 points.

Comment: English is my second official language, so this is the table in that link Second official language (4 points if you meet the minimum threshold in all four language abilities)

CLB Level(5andabove)   Speaking(5.0–9.0) Listening(5.0–9.0) Reading(4.0–9.0) Writing(5.0–9.0) Points(4)

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. Canada has two official languages, English and French. If you speak both, then you can designate one as your 'main' or 'first' language. Native speakers don't need to worry about these tables.

Comment: Looking at it again--now I'm not sure! You may need to contact them to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

CIC has a tool to calculate the points that you get for your language test: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-tool.asp